# Running pylint programmatically with the function epylint.py_run

Tags: python, pylint

When trying to run epylint.py_run to lint a file I pass in the filename and command-line options as a string, as specified in the [docs](http://docs.pylint.org/run.html). The file gets analyzed but the command-line options I pass aren't being applied. How can I get the function to apply the options I'm passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in epylint.Run which omit to give the options, hence your problem.

In your case you should rather use the `lint(filename, options)` function, where `options` should be passed as a list of strings).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in `epylint.Run`. I've submitted an issue. This should work:

```
def Run():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("Usage: %s [options] <filename or module>" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    elif not osp.exists(sys.argv[-1]):
        print("%s does not exist" % sys.argv[1])
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        sys.exit(lint(options=sys.argv[:-1], filename=sys.argv[-1]))
```